# View problem in Blender

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

In render result everything works but I can't see it in perspective mode. I started making project on Windows 7 and everything worked there but when I opened it again on Windows 10, I can't see things in perspective mode (for example plate color or render engine (Cycles))
Can anybody help me?

Edit: I'm beginner, I installed Blender yesterday, I'm sorry for my mistakes.

[image: In perspective mode][image: In render result]

Comment: Perspective or orthographic projection aren't a separate mode, unlike *Wireframe*, *Solid*, *Material Preview* and *Rendered*. Please update your description and/or add screenshots of the two different settings (render mode and what you're calling "perspective mode") to describe precisely what setting you're changing .

Comment: For clarification the second screenshot shows the final render result *Render > Render Image* (F12). By default this is a separate window that opens up. If you want to return to your 3D view you can simply close this window. If you just want to have a rendered preview, you can enable the *Rendered* mode in the 3D viewport (the rightmost little sphere icon). If you could tell me what your goal is, then I could write a full answer with screenshots.